# Trying to clone and run a python web app from github locally

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, git-clone

This is the web app I'm trying to clone: https://github.com/eddyharrington/Tendie-Tracker

Unfortunately, I'm not able to do it. I have followed all the steps provided. I'm a little confused with the last two steps.

Step 5: This is what I've typed

## App variable

SECRET_KEY=randomText

## DB variable

DATABASE_URL=postgres://{postgres}:{123}@{localhost}:{5432.0}/{tracker}

When I run the app, I get the following tracebacks.

```
  File "app.py", line 6, in <module>
    import tendie_dashboard
  File "C:\Users\Maithri\Desktop\Mini Project\Tendie-Tracker-master\tendie_dashboard.py", line 3, in <module>
    import tendie_budgets
  File "C:\Users\Maithri\Desktop\Mini Project\Tendie-Tracker-master\tendie_budgets.py", line 3, in <module>
    import tendie_categories
  File "C:\Users\Maithri\Desktop\Mini Project\Tendie-Tracker-master\tendie_categories.py", line 10, in <module>
    engine = create_engine(os.getenv("DATABASE_URL"))
  File "C:\Users\Maithri\Desktop\Mini Project\Tendie-Tracker-master\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\__init__.py", line 479, in create_engine
    return strategy.create(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Maithri\Desktop\Mini Project\Tendie-Tracker-master\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\strategies.py", line 56, in create
    plugins = u._instantiate_plugins(kwargs)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_instantiate_plugins'
```

Comment: The database URL is exactly like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting the values without the curly braces. You should have something like,

`DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:123@localhost:5432/tracker`

Also, port numbers are integer values, not floats.